# Dialog not displaying when button is clicked - Android

Tags: java, android, dialog

I am trying to get a `dialog` box to display.  Right now the program does not crash so there is no LogCat to display.  When the button is clicked, nothing happens that can be seen.  Is there a line of code I am missing that is preventing the `dialog` box from displaying?

**Java code:**

```
public class Results extends Activity {

    Button detailsBtn;
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.resultsmain);

        detailsBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.detailsBtn);
        detailsBtn.setText("Details");

        detailsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.resultsdetailsdisplay);
                dialog.setTitle("Detailssss - TESTING");

                TextView title = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.title);
                title.setText("TITLE - TESTING");

                Button close = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);

                close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

resultsdetailsdisplay.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/scroll" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because you haven't called the `show()` method for your `dialog`. 
Add

```
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Ah yes, that was it.  Never worked with ````dialogs```` before so I was not familiar with the commands.  Thanks @A--C.

Comment: @user1866707 You're welcome! You should also read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) to familiarize yourself with Dialogs.